# How to script sql server system table with data

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying "script"  a system table with its containing data in sql server management studio and I can't find any option to do that. There is one option to do this at database level but it doesn't include system tables. Just what ssms command Script table as -> DROP and CREATE To do but including data.
Any help would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Why would it include the system tables? Those should be managed by the system, not by the users.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve on a functional basis?

Comment: @Serpiton Well EF Code First put the Migration History on a system table and the problem is I mistakenly use the wrong database initializer so now I have a couple of databases with the wrong info there but I know the right info so I need to take the info from one table and pass it to the other. Thanks

Comment: @Will Marcouiller Well EF Code First put the Migration History on a system table and the problem is I mistakenly use the wrong database initializer so now I have a couple of databases with the wrong info there but I know the right info so I need to take the info from one table and pass it to the other. Thanks

Comment: If it's code first recreate the tables using the code then transfer the data, also in EF6 that table is [no more marked as system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456841.aspx)

Comment: @Serpiton I'm using EF5. Those DBs are in production so can´t use code I need a script to do the job. I thought there was a simple way to create the script.

Comment: Edit your question so that is clear that you need help for EF5, right now is generic for SQL-Server, sorry but the only think I know about EF are the ones I read to write my second comment.